# How to create intent for Firebase Android Tester App to open app when there is an update

Tags: android, android-intent, firebase-app-distribution

If Our internal users are using Firebase's App Tester app to test staging builds of our app, Is it possible to launch an intent to direct the user to that place inside the app? We have logic to direct the user to the play store to update on hard update requirement, but that doesn't work in staging, so we're looking to send the user to the Tester App directly and to then ideally open the details of the activity showing new version for download.

I've analyzed the APK ang to the following:

```xml
  <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f130129"
            android:name="dev.firebase.appdistribution.main.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter
                android:autoVerify="true">

                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="https" />

                <data
                    android:host="appdistribution.firebase.google.com" />

                <data
                    android:pathPrefix="/testerapps/" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter
                android:autoVerify="true">

                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="https" />

                <data
                    android:host="appdistribution.firebase.google.com" />

                <data
                    android:pathPattern="/testerapps/.*/releases/.*" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter
                android:autoVerify="true">

                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="https" />

                <data
                    android:host="appdistribution.firebase.google.com" />

                <data
                    android:pathPrefix="/accept/" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I feel like I'm just forgetting how to use intents properly, but I have the suspicion that

```xml
                <data
                    android:scheme="https" />

                <data
                    android:host="appdistribution.firebase.google.com" />

                <data
                    android:pathPattern="/testerapps/.*/releases/.*" />
```

is what I'm looking for, but I'm having the dangest time forming the intent to correctly open the app and direct the person to the app I want, any suggestions?